# Vercel Error: (Azure) OpenAI API key not found

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, openai-api, langchain

I implemented openAI API in my Next.js app with the help of langchain library and it works superb on localhost, but in Vercel (ProVersion) it throws an error:

> Error: (Azure) OpenAI API key not found
> at new OpenAIChat (file:///var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/llms/openai-chat.js:184:19)
> at new OpenAI (file:///var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/llms/openai.js:54:20)
> at /var/task/.next/server/pages/api/tasks/ai.js:63:21
> RequestId: 472c0bdb-dbbc-4cd4-95a3-1808d0b6a5ac Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
> Runtime.ExitError

the error leads to this code in the langchain node_module in my app:

```
this.openAIApiKey =
            fields?.openAIApiKey ?? getEnvironmentVariable("OPENAI_API_KEY");
        this.azureOpenAIApiKey =
            fields?.azureOpenAIApiKey ??
                getEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY");
        if (!this.azureOpenAIApiKey && !this.openAIApiKey) {
            throw new Error("(Azure) OpenAI API key not found");
        }
```

I put OPENAI_API_KEY environmental variable (identical to the one in my .env file) in Vercel:

[vercel_environmental_variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLho5.png)

In my app I put the OPENAI_API_KEY in .env file and load it in my backend:

```
const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;

const openAIModel = new OpenAI({
  modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  temperature: 0,
  maxTokens: 2000,
  openAIApiKey: apiKey,
});
```

I can even post and get API requests in localhost when I don't process the OPENAI_API_KEY in backend (langchain module takes it directly from my .env file)

```
const openAIModel = new OpenAI({
  modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  temperature: 0,
  maxTokens: 2000,
});
```

I also tried to change the model to OpenAIChat, it works same as OpenAI model on localhost, but again not in Vercel:

```
const openAIModel = new OpenAIChat({
  modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  temperature: 0,
  maxTokens: 2000,
});
```

I expect this would be enough to post requests to openAI API in Vercel, but it throws the same error again and again.

Does anyone have any idea what is missing here?

Thank you in advance!
Nasti

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error but, the error occured while using Langchain pinecone in nodejs .I was facing the error while using the OpenAIEmbeddings function .So if fixed it with this piece of code

```
    import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";

    const embeddingsArrays = await new OpenAIEmbeddings({
        openAIApiKey : process.env.OPEN_API_KEY
    }).embedDocuments(
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the environmental variable in Vercel and set it again, redeployed the project and it worked :-)